# Running the ruby plugin foo.rb for logstash-1.5.0beta1 version

Tags: plugins, logstash

I am trying to run the ruby plugin foo.rb as given on this link-http://logstash.net/docs/1.3.3/extending/example-add-a-new-filter .

As specified there I have created the ruby file inside `/logstash-1.5.0.beta1/lib/logstash/filters/foo.rb`

The command for running the conf file is given as-
`% logstash --pluginpath . -f example.conf`

What exactly should I write in the place of 'pluginpath'?

On specifying the path of foo.rb it is giving me the following errors-

```
Clamp::UsageError: Unrecognised option '--lib/logstash/filters/foo.rb'
signal_usage_error at /home/administrator/Softwares/logstash-1.5.0.beta1/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/clamp-0.6.3/lib/clamp/command.rb:103
find_option at /home/administrator/Softwares/logstash-1.5.0.beta1/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/clamp-0.6.3/lib/clamp/option/parsing.rb:62
parse_options at /home/administrator/Softwares/logstash-1.5.0.beta1/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/clamp-0.6.3/lib/clamp/option/parsing.rb:28
parse at /home/administrator/Softwares/logstash-1.5.0.beta1/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/clamp-0.6.3/lib/clamp/command.rb:52

run at /home/administrator/Softwares/logstash-1.5.0.beta1/lib/logstash/runner.rb:155
call at org/jruby/RubyProc.java:271              
run at /home/administrator/Softwares/logstash-1.5.0.beta1/lib/logstash/runner.rb:171
call at org/jruby/RubyProc.java:271
initialize at /home/administrator/Softwares/logstash-1.5.0.beta1/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/stud-0.0.18/lib/stud/task.rb:12
```

What should I do? Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Logstash's plugin handling changed significantly in 1.5, yet you're using the documentation from 1.3.3. The 1.5.0 documentation is at http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/logstash/current/_adding_a_sample_filter_to_logstash.html. While it looks very similar to the 1.3.3 documentation, make sure you follow it before debugging this further.

Comment: root@administrator-Inspiron-3520:~/Softwares/logstash-1.5.0.beta1# bin/logstash --pluginpath foo -f example.conf
Error: You specified a plugin path that does not exist: foo
You may be interested in the '--configtest' flag which you can
use to validate logstash's configuration before you choose
to restart a running system.

Comment: I followed the steps from  the link you suggested.I am now getting the above specified error. I think I am going wrong in executing the bin/logstash command or in placing the foo.rb in the correct place. Can you please help? Thanks in advance :)